# Right way to define an extension using IIFE

Tags: javascript

I've read some plugins (`jquery`, `dropzone`) and found that there are some different ways to declare an extension.

`jQuery`:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    factory( global );
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
    // jquery implementation
});
```

`dropzone`:

```
(function () {
    // dropzone implementation
}).call(this);
```

My way:

```
(function (global) {
    var myExtension = function () {};

    global.myExtension = myExtension;
}(window));
```

Why does javascript provide many ways to do a same work using only one `IIFE`? And... which's better?

Thank you!

**Update:**

Asynchronous function:

```
(async () => {
    // await something
})();
```

Comment: Your function works only in browsers where there is a `window` object. The other approaches work in arbitrary environments.

Comment: @Bergi You're right. When I start to learn `webpack`, it's always throwing the exception: `window is not defined`. It took me a very long time to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only shows how flexible Javascript is. You can achieve the same goal with different techniques. Some will tell you it's a great language feature, some will argue. At the end of the day all provided examples work the same. It's just a matter of your taste, project guidelines, etc. which one you will pick up.

PS. another way to declare an IIFE is:

```
!function() {

}()
```

:)